# Is a cofinite topological space a sequential space?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a (no finite) set endowed with the cofinite topology. Is this space a sequential space? My definition is that *a topological space $X$ is a sequential space if and only if the open sets $U$ are such that for any sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim_n x_n\subseteq U$ then there is $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_n\in U$ whenever $n\geq n_0$.*

My doubt is generated by the condition $\lim_n x_n\subseteq U$:

Suppose that the sequence has infinit different terms and let $x\in X$. Any open set $U$ containing $X$ is such that all but a finite number of points of the whole space belong to $U$. In particular, $U$ contain all but a finite number of members of the sequence, i.e. $x$ is a limit point for the sequence. This implies that $\lim_n x_n =X\not\subseteq U$.

Does this mean that I have to restrict to sequences such that $x_n=x_0$ whenever $n$ is greater than some $n_0\in\mathbb N$? (Notice that I need the sequence to have a limit, so it is not enough for the sequence to have contained, as a set, in a finite subset, e.g. $x_n=(-1)^n)$.

If I restrict myself to this kind of sequences then every closed set is sequentially closed, because the sequence is made of elements of the set.

Comment: Convergent sequences in cofinite topology are precisely sequences which are eventually constant. And so you are right, every subset in cofinite topology is sequentially open/closed.

Comment: @frakish Thanks a lot :).

Comment: @freakish any sequence with infinitely many different terms is convergent (and any point is a limit) in the cofinite topology. So not only the eventually constant ones (that holds for the discrete and the co-countable topology).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I guess he meant sequences that converge to a finite set (in fact to single point). Let he say the answer to your comment.

Comment: $\lim_n x_n \subseteq U$ is a very strong condition that will almost never be satisfied: the set of limits is empty, a singleton or $X$, and the empty set is irrelevant for the condition of sequential openness.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Well but that condition is in the definition of sequentally open. And I don't know why you say that. If the space isn't Hausdorff... and for what we need the empty set condition then?

Comment: @Dog_69 Because otherwise you'd have to consider divergent sequences too for the definition of sequentially open. If you leave it out, $1,2,1,2,\ldots$ obeys that the set of limits is a subset of $(0,1)$ (or in fact any set) but the sequence is not eventually in that set. etc. So without the non-empytyness the condition is almost meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any space an open set is sequentially open by definition.

The main observation for the cofinite topology (on an infinite set) is the following: there are exactly three types of sequence:

a. $(x_n)$ has infinitely many terms, so $\{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite.
Then $\lim (x_n)  =X$, i.e. every $p \in X$ is a limit of this sequence.

b. $(x_n)$ has finitely many distinct terms and is eventually constant, i.e. there is some $N$ and some $x \in X$ such that $\forall n \ge N: x_n = x$ and in that case $\lim (x_n) = \{x\}$.

c. $(x_n)$ has finitely many terms and is not eventually constant. Then this sequence has no limit, so $\lim_n (x_n) = \emptyset$.

Now suppose that $U$ is sequentially open, so for any sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ we have that *if* $\emptyset \neq \lim_n (x_n) \subseteq U$ *then* $(x_n)$ is eventually in $U$. Note that the non-emptyness is important (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) for another formulation of this definition: for all sequences $(x_n)$ and all $x$, if $x_n \to x$ and $x \in U$ then $(x_n)$ is eventually in $U$.)

We want to show that $U$ is open. If $U$ is empty, we are done, so assume $U\neq \emptyset$. Suppose we have a sequence with $\lim_n (x_n) \subseteq U$. If it is of type a. then $\lim (x_n) = X$ and $X = U$ and we are done. If it is of type b., we are also done as in particular $x \in U$ and $(x_n)$ is eventually $x$. Type c. is not an allowed "test sequence" for sequential openness. So in all cases $U$ is open and we're done.

We could also test (more easily) sequentially closed sets: suppose $F$ is infinite and sequentially closed. If $F \neq X$ pick $p \notin F$ and countably many different $x_n \in F$ for all $n$. Then $(x_n)$ would be a sequence in $F$ that converges to $p$ while $;p \notin F$, so $F$ would be not be sequentially closed at all. This contradiction came from assuming $F \neq X$, so $F=X$. Hence all sequentially closed sets are finite or $X$, as required.

So indeed the cofinite topology is a sequential space.

Comment: Thanks for noticing me that every open set is always sequentiality open. I didn't realize. Regarding the consideration $\lim_n x_n \neq\emptyset$, it is clear that if we allowed sequences with no limit then none set would be sequentially open (in any space)  doesn't it? Or there is a more powerful reason I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @Dog_69 see my other comment. And I think the best definition of sequentially open (formulationwise, with the non-emptyness condition it's equivalent to yours) is "for all sequences $(x_n)$ and for all $x$, if $x_n \to x$ and $x \in U$ then $(x_n)$ is eventually in $U$".

Comment: The problem I see with your definition @HennoBrandsma is the following: Imagine a topology on $\mathbb R$ such that the smallest neighbourhood for a point $x\in(1,2)$ is the interval itself. Now consider $U=(0,3/2)$ and the constant sequence $x_n=3/4$. It converges to $4/3\in U$ but the sequence isn't eventually in $U$. Hence it would not be sequentially open. However, with the other definition you couldn't say anything because $\lim_n x_n\not\subseteq U$.

Comment: I meant $x_n=7/4$, sorry.

Comment: @Dog_69 Your set $U$ is not open in this topology (as $\frac54$ is not interior e.g.)  and it's also not sequentially open by the sequence you gave. What's the problem?

Comment: I was reading the prove for sequentially openess implies is openess in cofinite spaces and I'm stuck on sequences of type 2. Namely, the set {2,3}
should satisfy the definition of sequentially open in N with the cofinite topology, but it is not open. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Dog_69 $\{2,3\}$ is not sequentially open, because $3,4,5,6,\ldots \to 2$ in the cofinite topology but it's not eventually in $\{2,3\}$. So that's what you're misunderstanding.

Comment: But this sequence does not verify the condition of type 2, i.e. $\lim x_n\not\subseteq \{2,3\}$. The sequence you say is of type 1.

Comment: I think the problem comes from my definition of sequentially open. Are you sure that my definition is equivalent to yours? I think that yours is stronger. The problem is that I can't remember where I copied the definition from (and if I copied it well). Maybe our definitions aren't equivalent.

Comment: @Dog_69 my definition is the same as Wikipedia ‘s and is the standard one, see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space)

Comment: @Dog_69 your definition is wrong for non-US spaces. US is a separation property between $T_1$ and Hausdorff that states the limits of sequences are unique

Comment: Yes yes. If there's a wrong definition that's mine. But do you understand my problem? According to my definition, $\{2,3\}$ is sequentially open. So you were right, the condition $\lim_n x_n\subseteq U$ is too strong. Or too permisive, in the sense that we must consider also sequences that have some limit points in $U$.